# Probability of winning cricket match

Tags: probability

Australia and India are playing a cricket match. The probability that Australia wins is 3/4.

Australia has to win 4 matches to win a series.(Example: if they play 5 matches their 4th match has to be the final match of the series).

After winning 4 matches they can't play more. How many matches do they have to play to win on this condition (5, 7 or 9. one of these has to be the answer)?